# How to receive data from multiple channels using for/select syntax?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have case where I need to receive data on multiple channels and somehow quit infinite for `loop`.

Here is simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    sumChannel := make(chan int)
    productChannel := make(chan int)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go compute(i, sumChannel, productChannel, &wg)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(sumChannel)
        close(productChannel)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-sumChannel:
            fmt.Println("sum")
        case <-productChannel:
            fmt.Println("prod")
        }
    }
}

func compute(i int, sumChannel chan int, productChannel chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    sumChannel <- i + i
    productChannel <- i * i
    wg.Done()
}
```

The problem is I get infinite `for` loop. I know that I should create new channel (for instance,`quit`) for quitting from loop. But, I really don't understand where to put signal to `quit`, because I don't know exact place where I can be sure that all goroutines finished.

Comment: You can use a nested select: https://go.dev/play/p/-Qh--tcWmO9. Note that simply closing a channel will not disable the receive operator, which is why you're getting an infinite loop: *"A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any previously sent values have been received."* https://go.dev/ref/spec#Receive_operator

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks. But, can you explain in simple words, how you are quitting if you are not sending any message to `quit` channel? You are just closing it.

Comment: Because, as quoted from the spec, a closed channel can receive immediately the `case <-quit:` case will be able proceed as soon as `close(quit)` is executed.

Comment: The last question. At the point of closing `quit` channel, why we can be so sure that all goroutines finished and we can quit? Is it bacause wg.Wait tells one goroutine to wait another?

Comment: Yes, because `wg.Wait()` proceeds only after all `wg.Done()` have been executed.

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question. In your code (and in my), you call `wg.Add` from main goroutine, but call `wg.Wait` from another one. Why? I don't understand `wg.Wait` blocks main goroutine or another one.

Comment: You're doing `wg.Add` in a loop of the main goroutine, only after that loop is done, and all the `wg.Add(1)` are executed, does the code proceed to schedule a child goroutine that will execute `wg.Wait()`. `wg.Wait()` does not block the main goroutine, it blocks the child goroutine.

Comment: And sure, one could say that `wg.Wait()` *indirectly* blocks the main goroutine because (in my version of the code) the main goroutine exits only after the `case <-quit:` case proceeds, and that happens only after `wg.Wait()` is done and `quit` channel is closed. But I don't think that that's a very useful way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the for loop in a go routine and then wait for the compute go routines to finish, you can cancel the loop from there:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    sumChannel := make(chan int)
    productChannel := make(chan int)
    closeChannel := make(chan bool)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go compute(i, sumChannel, productChannel, &wg)
    }

    go func() {
        loop:
        for {
            select {
            case <-sumChannel:
                fmt.Println("sum")
            case <-productChannel:
                fmt.Println("prod")
            case <-closeChannel:
                fmt.Println("break")
                break loop
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    closeChannel <- true

    fmt.Println("done")
}

func compute(i int, sumChannel chan int, productChannel chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    sumChannel <- i + i
    productChannel <- i * i
    wg.Done()
}
```

[Run it](https://goplay.space/#AzWS8rVsoZ0)

Comment: But, why you don't close all channels (sumChannel, productChannel, closeChannel)?

Comment: You can close them if you want, but it doesn't make sense, since I don't check for it anywhere. The for loop is break immediately if I send a value to the closeChannel, no more checks will be done on the other two channels.

Comment: You are break the select, not break the loop. If you want to break loop you must add label and break for loop from that label.